# Telegram bot switch_inline_query

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot that will have some inline query functionality and the idea is you click on a button and it asks you to chose chat to write a message to, and after you've written your message it should bring you back to the bot-chat. The problem is that I know there is an option to do that couldn't have found any example or docs how to. As far as I know, it may be achieved by using `switch_pm` but idk how to use it, and I didn't find any info about it... My code is looking like this right now

```
def inlineKeyboard(update, context):

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("1", switch_inline_query='')]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose: ', reply_markup=reply_markup)

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('test', inlineKeyboard))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
```